# Does having one-sided derivatives at every point guarantees the function to be differantiative at almost every point?

Tags: real-analysis

Question:

> Suppose $f$ is a (real-valued) function defined on the open invertal $(a,b)$. Additionally, suppose $f$ has one-sided derivaties at every point, i.e. the following two limits
> $$f'_+(x)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h},f'_-(x)=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
> exist (but not necessarily equal) for every $x\in (a,b)$. Let $S=\{x\in(a,b)|f'_-(x)\neq f'_+(x)\}$. Prove that $S$ is countable. (The result may not be true. If so, please tell me.)

Actually someone posted this question in calculus class, however after some consideration, I realized it is far beyond the scope of calculus. I first tried to find some counterexample and discovered that it is probably related to the limit points of $S$. (If $S$ contains a countable amount of limit points, then $S$ itself must be countable. Otherwise, one can obtain lots of information of $f$ by specifying all values at limit points of $S$).

There's even one more thing I have to say: I cannot even prove that $S$ cannot be $(a,b)$ (or $f$ must be differentiable at some point)!

Comment: This is true when $f$ is monotone.

Comment: However I cannot see anything special about being monotonic.